# In python, how can I display my output in a external window instead of python terminal?

Tags: python, timer, countdown

I try to make a countdown timer in python
could anyone help me? this is my code and I need something like the image

## this is my code and I need something like the image

```
    import time
    import datetime

    title = input("title: ")
    year = input("year: ")
    month = input("month: ")
    day = input("day: ")
    hour = input("hour: ")
    minute = input("minute: ")

    targetTime = datetime.datetime(int(year), int(month), int(day), int(hour), int(minute))

    def countdown(targetTime):
        while True:
            difference = targetTime - datetime.datetime.now()
            countHours, remainder = divmod(difference.seconds, 3600)
            countMinutes, countSeconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
            if difference.days == 0 and countHours == 0 and countMinutes == 0 and countSeconds == 0:
                print("BOOOM!")
                break
            print(  str(difference.days) + "d "
                  + str(countHours) + "h "
                  + str(countMinutes) + "m "
                  + str(countSeconds) + "s " + "until "
                  + str(title)
                  )
            time.sleep(1)
    
    countdown(targetTime)
```

## [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJONp.png

Answer (score 1):

do you really need to use tkinter?. i recommend you [pysimplegui](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI), it is pretty sweet

this is an example of a clock, which is (nearly) what you want:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import datetime

sg.set_options(border_width=0)
sg.theme('dark')


layout = [[sg.Text('Time: '), sg.Text('', key='_time_')], [sg.Quit()]]

window = sg.Window('Simple Clock', no_titlebar=True).Layout(layout)


def getTime():
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')


def main(gui_obj):
    while True:
        event, values = gui_obj.Read(timeout=10)

        if event in (None, 'Quit'):
            break

        gui_obj['_time_'].Update(getTime())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(window)
```

Comment: The eCookbook has a timer with a pause/reset that's another example:  https://pysimplegui.trinket.io/demo-programs#/async-windows-read-with-a-timeout/desktop-timer-widget
It's also in the project's Demo Programs

Answer (score 0):

Below are some tkinter commands

```
Entry : for entering users input
.get() : to get the user entered inputs and assign to your var's
label : for labelling text
button : to start the function
message box  : to display text finally
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not confident with Tkinter Classes approach and want to remain on your IDE Input principle - even so as suggested by Siva is the correct approach - use for displaying opencv or plt:
e.g. opencv

1. create empty image in desired size
2. create loop

- write text with actual counter time on image
- image show
- use dynamic wait Key to ensure every sec the pic gets updated

At the end, whatever suits you best is the best solution.